# HTML Not Loading Referenced Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made some javascript code, it didn't work so I tested if the file would even load.

In the **Javascript** code, I put:

```
alert("Hi");
```

And it didn't work. I proceeded to search for an answer, and followed all the directions to reference my script in the **HTML** code in the head element as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://squishling.co.uk/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<title>Hi I am a title!</title>
```

Then I put this into the javascript code after that didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("Am I working?!");
});
```

When I open the page I get nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Full HTML (I am making an example script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STUFF -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Head Content -->
    <link href="http://squishling.co.uk/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <title>Hi I am a title!</title>


  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Margin -->
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Title -->
      <h1>Hi I am a title!</h1>

      <form name="quizForm">
        <b>What is the creator of this site called?</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="quizOne"><br>
        <b>Guess: F__h. Something that swims in water.</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="quizTwo"><br>
        <button onclick="hi()">Hi</button>
      </form>


    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://squishling.co.uk/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Javascript:

```
var quizCorrect;
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("Am I working?!");
});
function checkCorrect() {
  var quizCorrect == 0;
  if(document.quizForm.quizOne.value == "Squishling") {
    var quizCorrect = quizCorrect + 1;
  }
  if(document.quizForm.quizTwo.value == "Fish") {
    var quizCorrect = quizCorrect + 1;
  }
  alert("You have scored " + quizCorrect + "/2.");
}
function hi() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

As reccomended I also tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STUFF -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Head Content -->
    <link href="http://squishling.co.uk/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <title>Hi I am a title!</title>


  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Margin -->
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Title -->
      <h1>Hi I am a title!</h1>
      See?
      <form name="quizForm">
        <b>What is the creator of this site called?</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="quizOne"><br>
        <b>Guess: F__h. Something that swims in water.</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="quizTwo"><br>
        <button onclick="hi()">Hi</button>
      </form>


    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://squishling.co.uk/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var quizCorrect;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Am I working?!");
    });
    function checkCorrect() {
      var quizCorrect == 0;
      if(document.quizForm.quizOne.value == "Squishling") {
        var quizCorrect = quizCorrect + 1;
      }
      if(document.quizForm.quizTwo.value == "Fish") {
        var quizCorrect = quizCorrect + 1;
      }
      alert("You have scored " + quizCorrect + "/2.");
    }
    function hi() {
      alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I have now put the scripts at the end of  at it still won't work.

Comment: Please put the script tag at the bottom rather than in the `head` tag

Comment: Where is the reference to _your_ script? All I see is jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: Certainly http://squishling.co.uk/ is missing the third `<script>` tag....

Comment: Even after you updated your question with all of the code examples, you STILL havent included your own script in the HTML

Comment: So does this not add my script: <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: @Moose He's not putting the script directly in the HTML, he's using an external file `script.js`.

Comment: It would if you added it to the code. but you never added it to the code so the script wont be called.

Comment: @Barmar, what line is the script included on?

Comment: @moose `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: @Squishling Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar, you answered some other question, not the question that I asked you, which was: What LINE NUMBER is the script included on inside the HTML?

Comment: @Moose Why do line numbers matter? He put the whole HTML file in the question.

Comment: @Barmar, I didnt realize that the code area was scrollable, I was under the impression that the code was incomplete. I see he moved it to the bottom of the body. Sorry about that!

Comment: You probably think I'm stupid, but what's a javascript console?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Open the developer tools by right clicking the page and clicking on Inspect or Inspect element

Comment: after the developer tools open select the console tab

Comment: I have found a console. It says I have 214 errors :P

Comment: @Squishling F12 in most browsers opens the developer tools, and the console is displayed at the bottom. This is the basic tool for debugging HTML/Javascript applications.

Comment: Every time I open it, it adds 15 errors

Comment: if you're getting 214 errors fix your errors then see if it works. Then come back if you still have problems. Or ask questions about individual errors. But if you're getting 214 errors then you should fix that first.

Comment: It won't tell me what errors I have...

Comment: Fix everything in red

Comment: So that means I don't have to fix anything

Comment: check my response below, remove extra "=" from var quizCorrect == 0

Comment: in the console you will see errors in red start from the beginning and fix each error one at a time. Many of your errors could be cascading errors from a handful of errors. start from the top of the console.

Comment: It says var quizCorrect == 0; doesn't have ; on the end

Comment: == is a comparison = is setting a value
should be var quizCorrect = 0;

Comment: = set value
== compair value loose
=== compair value stricked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two equal signs are throwing an error in console:

```
var quizCorrect == 0;
```

Remove one of them and make sure your script files are referenced in the head tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included the script.  You need to add another `<script>` tag pointing to your JS file.  Right now you are only importing 2 JS files.  One is for JQuery, the other is for Bootstrap.

What is the name of your JS file with your code in it?  It needs to be something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://squishling.co.uk/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="path/to/your/javascript/file.js"></script>

<title>Hi I am a title!</title>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I have <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> below it.

Comment: You need to add the entire code so we can see exactly what is going on.  Also, don't forget to check your console for errors. You might just be pointing to the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you have to code. If you are using jquery code inside the html you should use **Script tag `<script></script>`**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hi I am a title!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://squishling.co.uk/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Am I working?!");
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
```

Comment: I just did that, No luck. :-(

Comment: The point of the question is that he wants the script in an external `script.js` file, not embedded in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar he edited his question. The code what i mentioned in my answer the same code he had mentioned. But he didn't mention the script tag for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading existing js library named script.js. try to rename your js file name to something different, like myjs.js.

Correction:  itried your code and got error in the console complaining about "==" in your js code.
Change var quizCorrect == 0; TO var quizCorrect = 0; and it should run properly.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not getting what you are trying to do.

If you only want to show the alert on your html file you just need to do this

Just need to open a script on your html file
something like this:

```
<script>  alert("Am I working?!"); </script>
```

I reccomend to put all your scripts on your head section or work them apart and calling them

Comment: I'm testing for my script file